# Eclipse Editor issue in system.out.println()

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-formatter

My Eclipse editor formats this way

```
System.out
           .println("******Goal State Reached ***********");`
```

and I want it in one line like this

```
System.out.println("******Goal State Reached ***********");
```

How could I configure it to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Windows->Preferences->java(in left pane)->Formatter-> click on edit button`

You will see **Maximum Line width** if your line exceeds this limit than eclipse slices the line and pushes it to new line. You will need to edit this feature.

**Note**- Buit-in eclipse Features **CANNOT** be edited (i.e. when you clicked edit button observe the profile),so you will have to create your own profile and use it

Hope this helps!

Good luck!